# EasyAdminBundle count and statistique

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I want to add to the administration page of EasyAdminBundle (/ admin), the number of registered users for example, or the number of registered restaurants (for example). (statistics from my business layer) or even add statistics of the number of registrants, number of registrations of the day, total number of registrants, see even the number of visitors, ...

I'm starting with EasyAdminBundle and I don't know if it's possible or how to do it, ...

thanking you!

Comment: What version of easyadmin are you using?

Comment: my version easyadmin is 3.x

Comment: In 3.x you have at least 1 dashboard controller and one crud controller per entity easy admins  can manage. You can implement your own logic the same way you would do in a normal controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example when you want to make a custom login with the EasyAdmin login template:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/dashboards.html#login-form-template

If you want to make a custom dashboard with EasyAdmin, follow this:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/dashboards.html#content-page-template

They don't provide full example in the documentation but regarding the way a custom login form is implemented with EasyAdmin , It should not be hard!